# ionic build android : Error :Failed to run “java -version ”

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

windows 10

ionic 1.7.15

please help me

ionic build android

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode, sharing)


Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME environment variable should be set to java jdk installation path folder not jre installation path. As per your error trace, your java home is set to jre path which could be the issue